# how to pause the console in F# language

Tags: f#

Please tell me how I can pause the console window when running the program in F#.

```
open System
let myList = [0..9]
let myFunction =
for n in myList do
    Console.WriteLine(n)
myFunction
```

Comment: What do you mean, "pause the console window"? If you want to halt the output, a `Ctrl-Z` in a Linux terminal will do that. (`fg` or `bg` resumes the program.)

Comment: im using windows.. in C++ we write code system("pause") like that is there any way to hold the window

Comment: @user1717327 - I think you need to improve your question writing skills, your questions are often unclear.  See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider to wrap the pause function in compiler directives, since you probably don't want to have the same effect in release code.

```
(* your code here *)
#if DEBUG
System.Console.ReadKey(true) |> ignore 
#endif
```

Answer (score 16):

I am guessing that you want the console to display the output after the program execution finishes.

You could put this line in the end of your snippet

`Console.ReadKey() |> ignore`

to 'pause' the console in that sense.

Comment: Normally we use `System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore` as this will eliminate a compiler warning

Comment: @JohnPalmer - Yes, thats true, I wasn't giving the complete snippet here, have edited the answer. Thanks

Comment: @user1717327 - glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

```ml
// When running in debug mode and using Visual Studio to run the program,  
// one may miss the results as the program runs to the end and exists.  
// Since running normally, i.e. Visual Studio Ctrl-F5, will add an pause
// automatically the pause is only shown when in debug mode.  
let pause () =  
  match System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached with  
  | true ->  
      printfn "\nPress any key to continue."  
      System.Console.ReadKey(true) |> ignore  
  | false -> ()  

pause ()
```