# How to refactor a function using "ignore"

Tags: f#

**When should I use "ignore" instead of "()"?**

I attempted to write the following:

```
let log = fun data medium -> ()
```

I then received the following message:

> Lint: 'fun _ -> ()' might be able to be refactored into 'ignore'.

So I updated the declaration to the following:

```
let log = fun data medium -> ignore
```

**Is there any guidance on why I might use one over the other?**

My gut tells me that I should use ignore when executing an actual expression.
In this case though, I'm declaring a high-order function.

**Are my assumptions accurate?**

Comment: `let log = fun data medium -> ()` returns unit, while `let log = fun data medium -> ignore` returns a function that returns unit – one does not replace the other. The lint message indicates that the former, other than being binary rather than unary, is semantically the same as `ignore`.

Comment: As is often noted, if you use `ignore` or get a compile message to use `ignore` you should really look at the code and understand why, typically it is a design issue rather than which way should it be done. As I often note I rarely need `ignore` and it is almost always with user I/O e.g. [Console.ReadKey() |> ignore](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24215845/1243762) or interacting with non functional code such as .NET methods, e.g. [A Computation Expression wrapper for StringBuilder](http://www.fssnip.net/d5)

Comment: In my case, my log function is meant to interact with the outside world via I/O.

Comment: I guess, it's Lint's fault. It was supposed to suggest replacing `fun x -> ()` with `ignore`. Note, it suggested you to replace *the entire function*, while you only changed its *body*, which is not what Lint has asked. In any case, your `log` has two arguments, and there should be no suggestion to replace it with `ignore`.

Comment: I think the question got -1 because what the title suggested was mixing two concepts - but I think it is perfectly valid question to ask given the linter message. I changed the title to something that I think is more appropriate and will not confuse people.

Answer (score 6):

The linter message that you got here is a bit confusing. The `ignore` function is just a function that takes anything and returns unit:

```
let ignore = fun x -> ()
```

Your `log` function is a bit similar to `ignore`, but it takes two parameters:

```
let log = fun data medium -> ()
```

In F#, this is actually a function that returns another function (currying). You can write this more explicitly by saying:

```
let log = fun data -> fun medium -> ()
```

Now, you can see that a *part* of your function is actually the same thing as `ignore`. You can write:

```
let log = fun data -> ignore
```

This means the same thing as your original function and this is what the linter is suggesting. I would not write the code in this way, because it is less obvious what the code does (it actually takes two arguments) - I guess the linter is looking just for the simple pattern, ignoring the fact that sometimes the refactoring is not all that useful.

Answer (score 3):

**Never**, at least not in the way shown in the question.

Substituting between `ignore` and `()` is not meaningful, as they are different concepts:

- `ignore` is a generic function with one argument and unit return. Its type is `'T -> unit`.
- `()` is the only valid value of type `unit`. It is not a function at all.

Therefore, it's not valid to do the refactor shown in the question. The first version of `log` takes two curried arguments, while the second version takes three.

What Lint is trying to suggest isn't quite clear. `ignore` is a function with one argument; it's not obvious how (or why) it should be used to refactor a method that takes two curried arguments. `fun _ _ -> ()` would be an okay and quite readable way to ignore two arguments.